# Fighting telemarketing: application to make telemarketers waste as much time as possible

Tags: android, ios, phone

Like many I am not a huge fan of telemarketing. I know there exist applications that automatically reject call from telemarketers based on some blacklists. This is quite convenient but it doesn't go far enough for my taste.

I am looking for Android and iPhone applications to make them waste as much time as possible. The application would - instead of simply rejecting the telemarketer's call - pick up the phone and imitate a human voice, with the goal of confusing or making the telemarketer wait.

For example, the application could:

- say "Please hold the line, I'll be right back / in two minutes"
- repeat "Sorry I cannot hear you" with some long pauses between.
- etc.

Anything creative to make the telemarketer stay longer on the line is good.

Free is better, but I am willing to pay for it. It's ok if the phone needs to be rooted/jailbroken.

Comment: Just connect them to an instance of [Eliza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA).

Comment: "Excuse me, there's someone at the door"  set your phone down beside a radio.

Comment: "I'd love to.  How much money"  (X second pause)  "Just a minute let me find my wallet" (pause)  recording of rummaging.  "Ok, lets have the details one more time"

Comment: IMO this is a tad evil. Telemarketers are people too and need to make as many calls as possible a day to bring home the butter. Simply politely stating you don't want to be called back and/or blocking the number should be sufficient.

Comment: @Huey:  Leeches also need to make a living, and they can only do it by sucking your blood, otherwise they starve to death.  Unlike telemarketers, who presumably have free will, for leeches it isn't even a choice.  I assume if you want to be nice to telemarketers, you also want to be nice to leeches?  (Remember, even leeches have mothers).

Comment: [Nomorobo](https://www.nomorobo.com/) is a free black-listing service. It's reduced, but far from eliminated, robocalls. Don't expect telemarketers to be fooled for long, by *Eliza*... they hang up quickly if they're not making progress.

Answer (score 5):

[Hellooo, this is Lenny!](https://www.reddit.com/r/itslenny/)

Unfortunately, the original site (www.itslenny.com) is down, but you can find lots of videos, and imitators, on Youtube and elsewhere.

A brief Google search [turned up](http://www.tormentingtelemarketers.com/2015/05/telemarketers-probably-dont-like-lenny/) this repo: https://github.com/lgaetz/freepbx-Its_Lenny

This seems like exactly what you want, though perhaps not the most user friendly.

Comment: some recordings: https://www.reddit.com/r/itslenny/

Comment: The github listed in this answer seems to have closed, a replacement can be found at https://github.com/reconwireless/freepbx-itslenny