# Android "AdBlock" for spam phone calls?

Tags: android, phone, spam

**Purpose**: spam phone calls are annoying (understatement). It seems it would be somewhat trivial to have an app on your phone which behaves similar to AdBlock.

Most spam block calls are like a version of AdBlock where you have to first see all ads. I would like to have a spam block app which is similarly proactive to AdBlock.

**Features:**

- Maintain list of "spam numbers" which is subscribed to a central database (a list unique to me is basically meaningless)

  - I want it to be more proactive than "mark this call as spam" which many apps do, I normally don't get double calls from the same spammers
- When receiving an incoming call from a number on the spam list, does either "spam call incoming" or "blocked spam call" notifications or somehow clearly shows it's a spam number.

Really, that's essentially it. Other features are bonus.

Comment: Note: This question is essentially a duplicate of http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10807/fighting-telemarketing-application-to-make-telemarketers-waste-as-much-time-as

Comment: @CRSouser it's not even close to a duplicate, this is looking for something specific with a different end goal. It is very likely the results of the question you suggest as a duplicate will not meet my needs (and vice versa).

Comment: The blacklist function mentioned in the other post IS what you are asking for.

Comment: No, @enderland: the main target in that question is *to make them waste as much time as possible*, not to block the calls.

Comment: There is a big difference between "waste telemarketers' time" and "centralized blacklist"

Answer (score 3):

My personal favourites are

[Whoscall- Caller ID&Block](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gogolook.callgogolook2)

The best app for identifying and blocking calls.you can instantly identify the source of calls and text messages even if the caller’s number is not in your contact list,whoscall also helps you block specific numbers.

more than 20 million calls are filtered and about 500,000 malicious calls are blocked by users everyday

[image]

and

[TrueCaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller)

Description
Truecaller is replacing the phonebook to make it more intelligent and useful. It lets you search beyond your existing contact list, identify unknown incoming calls, block calls you don’t want to receive, and make personal contact suggestions based on time and place – so you never have to leave the service to find the right contact.

[image]

Comment: I would vote for trucaller and it also works on other OS's so you benefit from their input too.

Answer (score 1):

TrueCaller, the top pick for Android, is available for iOS, too.

**Truecaller**: Number Search & Spam Identification by True Software Scandinavia AB
https://appsto.re/us/YXHTA.i

> We started off as an app to identify unknown numbers and block spam calls. Many people do not bother saving phone numbers anymore because they rely on the ability of Truecaller to find the right contact information, and identify the name behind a number, regardless of it being saved into their phone. We want to make this a more simplified and streamlined process so you have all the current information on people and businesses you need without ever having to leave the app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe NoMoRobo has the features that you need: http://www.nomorobo.com/

> "No more annoying robocalls and telemarketers."

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this software meet the needs of the asker? What are your personal experiences with it that support you recommending it?

Comment: @winterblood Sorry they don't provide details until you sign up. They only talk in the video. It depends on the user's service provider. I have no experience with it. I use another service (provided by my VOIP provider and works differently).

Answer (score 0):

You might try Klink. This app displays caller information either from your contact list, from connected apps (eg linked in etc) and from their own databases.

This can let you see in advance who is calling.