# Android number and blocker advisor app

Tags: android

I need a Andoid app similar to [Mobile Number & Phone Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=and.p2l) that works on at least Android 4.0.4 (older is fine).

The features it must have is telling me the city, state, county, and last time called. It also must be able to identify known scam and debt collector numbers and allow a  way to block numbers. It must be free and must be less than 10MB (6 preferred).

Comment: So basically a mashup of [CallerID](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_callerid) and Call Blacklist / [Call Blocker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97)? No personal experience with this kind – but according to my lists linked above, [Whoscall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gogolook.callgogolook2) looks like a good match. A perfect match even for your "size requirement" (5.5 MiB) :)

Comment: see this answer http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17655/8705

Comment: @unique_id That answeer suggested two different apps, I was lookin for one.

Comment: @lzzy That looks like it will satisfy my requirements...please make it an actual answer in the high chance that I accept it (bout to install and test now)

Comment: @lzzy, the only thing that makes it not 100% (but wasn't specified though my current (now old) app could do, is also say the town/city the number is in. But having state and country is good enough for now, ty for the answer.