# iOS "AdBlock" for spam phone calls?

Tags: ios, iphone-app, phone, spam, ad-blocker

I have the same requirements like [this Call AdBlock for Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17606/android-adblock-for-spam-phone-calls), but it should run on iOS/iPhone. I wish to buy the app non-recurring (*no subscription for filter list*). I am based in Europe, international support is essential.

Answer (score 2):

**[Truecaller](https://www.truecaller.com)**

Truecaller finds contact details globally given name or telephone number, and has an integrated caller ID service to achieve call-blocking functionality

- Search & Identify any phone number
- Block unwanted calls or hidden numbers
- Works with the new CallKit from Apple, so it's integrated in the Phone interface.